# Two commands on a single line in inputrc

Tags: bash, unix

I'd like to use the "up" key to move up through history in my bash shell, but when I do this:

> ```
> "\e[A": history-search-backward
> "\e[B": history-search-forward
> ```
>
> After hitting "up", the cursor doesn't forward do the end of the word.
>   How can I concatenate two commands? I tried 
>       "\e[A": history-search-backward end-of-line
>   as well as other things and nothing worked...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.inputrc`

```
# By default up/down are bound to previous-history
# and next-history respectively. The following does the
# same but gives the extra functionality where if you
# type any text (or more accurately, if there is any text
# between the start of the line and the cursor),
# the subset of the history starting with that text
# is searched (like 4dos for e.g.).
# Note to get rid of a line just Ctrl-C
#"\M-[A": history-search-backward
#"\M-[B": history-search-forward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[A": history-search-backward
```

Comment: how is this different from the configuration mentioned in the question?

Comment: This is what I started with... It doesn't push the cursor to the end of the line.